# Using jquery to see if selector pulled any divs, find a div thats specific to example page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I'm pretty new to jquery, this is what i need help with: Using jquery to see if a selector pulled any divs, find a div thats specific to example page.  See if first condition is false and if so redirect to example page.  Thanks for any help!

Jquery partial code: "

```
 $('.assessment-start').click(function () {

        $('#startAssessmentDialog').empty();

        //block
        $('#startAssessmentDialog').block(_blockUISettings);
        //block
        var link = $('#startAssessmentDialog').attr('link');

        AjaxUtil.Services.PageProxy.SendData(link, GLOBAL._HTTPVerbs.GET, {},
            function (data) {
                var $data = $(data);
                $('#startAssessmentDialog').html($data.find('#surveyContainer'));
                $('div[name*="*"]').val('*');</script>

                // hide the unmapped capability areas
                $("#unmappedCapabilityAreas").hide();
                // unblocking
                $('#startAssessmentDialog').unblock();
                // unblocking
            },
            function (exception) {
                AjaxUtil.DefaultExceptionHandler(exception);
                $('#startAssessmentDialog').unblock();
            }
        );
```

"

Html code:

```
<div link="/Survey/details/@Global.CGSs[Model.CGSVersionID.Value].SelfAssessmentSurveyResourceID/@Model.ResourceID" id="startAssessmentDialog" class="noDisplay">

</div>
```

Comment: Post your `HTML` and `JS` code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something:

```
if( $('#selector').length ) {
  // do something if selector pulled a div
} else {
  // do something if selector not pulled a div
  // for page redirect write following line
  window.location = 'YOUR_URL';
}
```

`$('#selector').length` will check the exists of `div` with `id=selector`.

Comment: in the else I need to redirect to a page, what would be the jquery code to write in the else { to redirect to a page?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing if selector got any divs:

```
var selector_pulled_divs=($(selector).filter("div").length!=0)
```

We'd need some code to work with to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `nodeName` property:

```
if ($(".selector").get(0).nodeName == 'div') { \\do stuff }
```